# boost/beast io_context, is it possible to call it for a second run()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, beast

I've got simple io_context object which is used to initialize ssl_stream object (using async_resolve, async_connect and async_handshake).

On a different scope, it's used to call async_read and async_write to pass IO in that connection.

the async calls are performed from within coroutine (boost::asio::spawn(io_context_, [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield)). each one of the stages above is executed on a different such coroutine. In order to execute the coroutine, the underlying io_context of the ssl_stream should be in run() method.

However, since those 2 methods are separated, than a single run() stage wouldn't be enough. After the connection initialization will be finished, the first run() will be terminated, so a second run() instance should be called right after the second coroutine (that does the IO ops) is called)

However, I observed that the second run goes out immediately, and doesn't perform the recently inserted spawn. Any idea how to overcome this scenario ? or the only alternative is to run the whole connection lifecycle in single coroutine, or call the run on a separated thread that never quits...

Here's the semi-pseudo code of my scenario :

```
boost::asio::io_context io_context_;
std::optional<boost::beast::tcp_stream> stream_;
std::optional<boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver> resolver_;

//STAGE 1

boost::asio::spawn(io_context_, [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
    results = resolver_->async_resolve(host_,port_ , yield);
    ssl_stream_->next_layer().async_connect(results, yield);
    ssl_stream_->async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client, yield);
}
try {
 io_context_.run();
} catch (...) {
}

//STAGE 2

beast::flat_buffer buffer;
http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;

boost::asio::spawn(io_context_, [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
  beast::get_lowest_layer(*ssl_stream_).expires_after(kOpTimeout);
  auto sent = http::async_write(*ssl_stream_, beast_request, yield);
  auto read = http::async_read(*ssl_stream_, buffer, res, yield);
});

try { 
  io_context_.run();
  return res;
} catch (...) {
}
```

Comment: The overwhelming time spent answering was making your question code self-contained. Please be considerate and post self-contained question code. That way you would have found the syntax error and missing `ssl_stream_` and save others time to correctly initialize ssl contexts etc.

Comment: @sehe, sounds just and right, I just wanted to emphasis the idea ... I appreciate your huge effort for the boost community here, by providing full answer that actually works. next time I'll write full example that pass compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but a-typical. As documented, in order to be able to re-run after the service ran out of work (I.e. [returning 0 handlers when executed](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context.run.overload1.return_value)), you need to call `restart()` (previously `reset()`):

> A normal exit from the `run()` function implies that the `io_context` object is stopped (the `stopped()` function returns `true`). Subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` will return immediately unless there is a prior call to `restart()`.

### Demo

Here is a demo based on your snippet:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace ssl   = net::ssl;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
using net::ip::tcp;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct X {
    std::string host_ = "www.example.com";
    std::string port_ = "https";

    static auto constexpr kOpTimeout = 3s;

    net::io_context                                     io_context_;
    ssl::context                                        ctx_{ssl::context::sslv23_client};
    std::optional<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ssl_stream_{std::in_place,
                                                                    io_context_, ctx_};
    std::optional<tcp::resolver> resolver_{std::in_place, io_context_};

    X() { ctx_.set_default_verify_paths(); }

    void STAGE1() {
        net::spawn(io_context_, [&](net::yield_context yield) {
            try {
                auto results = resolver_->async_resolve(host_, port_, yield);
                ssl_stream_->next_layer().async_connect(results, yield);
                ssl_stream_->async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client, yield);
            } catch (std::exception const& e) {
                std::cerr << "Whoops in " << __LINE__ << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
                throw;
            }
        });

        if (io_context_.stopped())
            io_context_.restart();

        try {
            io_context_.run();
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "Whoops in " << __LINE__ << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
            throw;
        }
    }

    auto STAGE2() {
        beast::flat_buffer                 buffer;
        http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;

        http::request<http::empty_body> beast_request(http::verb::get, "/", 11);
        beast_request.set(http::field::host, "www.example.com");

        net::spawn(io_context_, [&](net::yield_context yield) {
            try {
                beast::get_lowest_layer(*ssl_stream_).expires_after(kOpTimeout);
                /*auto sent =*/ http::async_write(*ssl_stream_, beast_request, yield);
                /*auto read =*/ http::async_read(*ssl_stream_, buffer, res, yield);
            } catch (std::exception const& e) {
                std::cerr << "Whoops in " << __LINE__ << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
                throw;
            }
        });

        if (io_context_.stopped())
            io_context_.restart();

        try {
            io_context_.run();
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "Whoops in " << __LINE__ << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
            throw;
        }
        return res;
    }
};

int main() {
    X x;

    x.STAGE1();
    std::cout << x.STAGE2();
}
```

Prints, locally:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Age: 533333
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 18 Dec 2022 21:50:21 GMT
Etag: "3147526947+ident"
Expires: Sun, 25 Dec 2022 21:50:21 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Server: ECS (bsa/EB20)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 1256

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        
    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Notes

[Again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74791925/85371), make `buffer` a member, because its context **will** matter for any subsequent traffic on the connection.

Also, don't use `run()` to find out when things are "done". You can use futures, or any other way of synchronization:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7baa080be83515d2)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace ssl   = net::ssl;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = beast::http;
using net::ip::tcp;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;

struct Client {

    Client(net::any_io_executor ex) : ssl_stream_{ex, ctx_} {
        ctx_.set_default_verify_paths();
    }

    void connect(std::string host, std::string port = "https") {
        host_ = host;

        std::packaged_task<void(std::string, std::string, net::yield_context)> task{
            [this](std::string host, std::string port, net::yield_context yield) {
                tcp::resolver resolver_{ssl_stream_.get_executor()};
                auto          results = resolver_.async_resolve(host, port, yield);
                ssl_stream_.next_layer().async_connect(results, yield);
                ssl_stream_.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client, yield);
            }};
        auto fut = task.get_future();

        net::spawn(ssl_stream_.get_executor(),
                   std::bind(std::move(task), std::move(host), std::move(port),
                             std::placeholders::_1));

        return fut.get();
    }

    using Response = http::response<http::dynamic_body>;
    Response makeRequest(std::string target, duration kOpTimeout = 300ms) {
        http::request<http::empty_body> beast_request(http::verb::get, target, 11);
        beast_request.set(http::field::host, host_);

        std::packaged_task<Response(net::yield_context)> task{
            [kOpTimeout, req = std::move(beast_request), this](net::yield_context yield) {
                Response res;

                beast::get_lowest_layer(ssl_stream_).expires_after(kOpTimeout);
                /*auto sent =*/http::async_write(ssl_stream_, req, yield);
                /*auto read =*/http::async_read(ssl_stream_, buffer_, res, yield);

                return res;
            }};
        auto fut = task.get_future();

        net::spawn(ssl_stream_.get_executor(), std::move(task));

        return fut.get();
    }

  private:
    ssl::context                         ctx_{ssl::context::sslv23_client};
    beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> ssl_stream_;

    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    std::string        host_;

};

int main() {
    net::thread_pool ioc(1);    // 1 thread is enough
    Client x(make_strand(ioc)); // strand only required if you have multiple IO threads

    x.connect("httpbin.org");
    std::cout << x.makeRequest("/delay/2", 3s) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Second request will time out: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << x.makeRequest("/delay/5", 1s); // timeout

    ioc.join(); // wait for service to complete
}
```

Locally:

[image]

Comment: I should mention, I have bad experiences with letting exceptions emanate from `spawn`-ed stackful coros. Apparently something about the stack-switching makes it bad to catch exceptions - perhaps only if by reference. Notice that the packaged_task side-steps all these by marshaling the exception through [`promise::set_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_exception) for you internally.